# Python regex multiline correct definition

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm trying to define a regex in serveral lines using `re.VERBOSE` but python is adding a newline symbol. eg

When not using multiline

```
In [1]: pat = re.compile(r'''(?P<host>(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})( - )(?P<user_name>(\w+|-)).''')
   ...: pat 
re.compile(r'(?P<host>(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})( - )(?P<user_name>(\w+|-)).',re.UNICODE)
```

But when trying to define as multiline

```
In [2]: pat = re.compile(r'''\ 
   ...: (?P<host>(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\ 
   ...: ( - )(?P<user_name>(\w+|-)).''', re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)    
In [4]: pat
re.compile(r'\\n(?P<host>(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\\n( - )(?P<user_name>(\w+|-)).',
re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE|re.VERBOSE)
```

I keep getting a `\n` where the next part of regex is define but it shouldn't.

How am I supouse to define a multiline regex?

Comment: `'''`'or`"""` is for a freeline text. That means, what ever you write inside the tripple quotes is read as is. If you have a newline in that, then its automatically considered as new line.

Answer (score 1):

There's no inherent problem with having newlines in your regex when you use the [`re.VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) flag, as whitespace is ignored, with an important caveat:

> Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character
> class, or **when preceded by an unescaped backslash**

Your first problem is that you are adding an unnecessary `\` to the end of each of the lines in your regex, and they are then appearing in the regex, making the newlines preceded by an unescaped backslash and thus required for a match. Consider this trivial example:

```py
pat = re.compile(r'''
\d+
-
\d+''', re.VERBOSE)
pat
# re.compile('\n\\d+\n-\n\\d+', re.VERBOSE) - note newlines in the regex
pat.match('24-34')
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='24-34'> - but it still matches fine
pat = re.compile(r'''\
\d+\
-\
\d+''', re.VERBOSE)
pat
# re.compile('\\\n\\d+\\\n-\\\n\\d+', re.VERBOSE)
pat.match('24-34')
# nothing
pat.match('\n24\n-\n34')
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='\n24\n-\n34'> - newlines required to be matched
```

Your other problem is that your regex is attempting to match whitespace in this capture group:

```
( - )
```

To match whitespace when you have the `re.VERBOSE` flag set, you must follow the rules and escape it or put it in a character class. For example:

```py
pat = re.compile(r'( - )', re.VERBOSE)
pat.match(' - ')
# nothing - the spaces in the regex are ignored
pat.match('-')
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='-'>  - matches just the `-`

pat = re.compile(r'(\ -[ ])', re.VERBOSE)  # important whitespace treated appropriately
pat.match(' - ')
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match=' - '>  - matches the string because whitespace rules followed
```

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gQGS6U/4)

Comment: But I've tried that too and still getting the same results. Even more, the whitespaces are not being ignored:

This is the compiled regex without backslash and there are some whitespaces and the \n which as far I understand they shouldn't be there

```re.compile('\n    (?P<host>(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})\n    ( - )\n    (?P<user_name>(\\w+|-)).\n    (?P<time>\\d\\d.\\D\\D\\D.\\d{4}.\\d\\d.\\d\\d.\\d\\d .....)...\n    (?P<request>\\w*\\s\\S*\\s\\w*\\S\\d.\\d*)', re.VERBOSE)```

Thanks for answering

Comment: @sergiohzlz the whitespace is there because it is in your string. However the use of the `re.VERBOSE` flag means that it will be ignored when matching. Note though that when you *want* to match whitespace, you need to either escape it with a \, or use `\s` or use a character class e.g. `[ ]`. This applies to the whitespace in your `( - )` capture group. See for example https://regex101.com/r/gQGS6U/3 where I have demonstrated use of escaping or a character class.

Comment: @sergiohzlz please see my edit

Comment: @sergiohzlz did that resolve your issues?